# Why haven't Stack Overflow implemented their websocket at newest questions and views of questions?

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow uses [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). That is good. But why do we have to continuously refresh a page for getting new questions posted?

Whenever I use it, I refresh page more than 500 times and sometimes even my browser says:

> Google Chrome cannot find server at stackoverflow.com

I have to disconnect and reconnect with my Wi-Fi and then have to use it. The same is with question views.

I think they need to implement WebSocket at that section also.

Comment: There are too many questions posted on stackoverflow.com. If you are looking at specific tags, I am pretty sure it will do it.

Comment: Only the main page does not use web sockets. Go to a specific tag and enjoy the show!

Comment: @MartijnPieters one min i think i should give a check on it.

Comment: It is working. Thanks. But can it be just that i choose two or three tags and enjoy the show with popcorn also.

Comment: Sure you can. Search for `[tagone] [or] [tagtwo] [or] [tagthree]` in the search box. Bring popcorn.

Comment: i think i need popcorn and cold drink also because its working. Thanks to all guys and good thing is that it notifies also. So, when i am cross-tab i can know about new questions. Stackoverflow is bit clever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow gets an extremely high volume of new questions. Check out [this view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) and look at the times; you would be getting constant updates, putting extra strain on things.

Note that tag-specific pages *do* update automatically; since each tag would get fewer updates than the whole site.

As for the rest; it seems like you have a connection problem somehow. That's really a separate issue.

Comment: well, ahh i know that it somehow difficult. New questions are displayed on refresh. Why they can't let it go like when new answer is posted it notifies and Let the user to load new answer. I have problem only for stackoverflow.com not for others like facebook, google+ or any other websites. I haven't read browser issues. But i think continously refreshing do it.